# How to fill out a Post Request for a Direct Login authorization in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I having a question about a post request authorization.

I need to make a request with the following data to get a token.

POST /my/logins/direct HTTP/1.1
**Authorization**: DirectLogin username="aaaaa",   password="686876",  consumer_key="GET-YOUR-OWN-API-KEY-FROM-THE-OBP"
**Content-Type:** application/json
**Cookie:** JSESSIONID=7h1ssu6d7j151u08p37a6tsx1
**Host**: 127.0.0.1:8080
**Connection:** close
**User-Agent:** Paw/2.3.3 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.3) GCDHTTPRequest
**Content-Length:** 0

I have some node.js code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://apisandbox.openbankproject.com/my/logins/direct",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        /* Authorization header */
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", DirectLogin username="ssmsskan",
password="passs",
consumer_key="wbr3y4vddddddddfffgmcaxxdj2hxok5xt");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mobile", "false");
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

I know that the problem is in lin

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", DirectLogin username="aaaaaa",
    password="pass",
    consumer_key="wbr3y4vcekbcvukgbkbsoandsapjjjjdj2hxok5xt");
```

But I do not know how to put my **DirectLogin information** on  **`xhr.setRequestHeader`**

Thaks

Comment: What is the problem your getting? Whats the error? Without knowing for sure I can see `Direct Login...` should be in quotes

Comment: The error is _Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list_ in `xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", DirectLogin username="ssmsskan",
password="passs",
consumer_key="wbr3y4vddddddddfffgmcaxxdj2hxok5xt");` I am aware that that is not the right way to do the authorization, but I do not know how to do it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple quote syntax issue. Should be

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'DirectLogin username="ssmsskan",
password="passs",
consumer_key="wbr3y4vddddddddfffgmcaxxdj2hxok5xt"');
```

Comment: Yes, the syntax error disappeared. Now I have the error **Request header field X-Mobile is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

Comment: Thats a very different issue. I would google and do some research on it. If theres no info out there post a new question on it.

Comment: I deleted the line `xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mobile", "false");` and resulted, thanks